# script for macd addressing in cryptocurrency

Tags: python, numpy, trading, cryptocurrency

```
def initialize(state):

state.counter = 0

@schedule(interval="1h",symbol="BTCUSDT”)

If state.counter < 4: state.counter += 1 Else: state.counter = 0

if counter == 4: (every four hours)

macd = data.macd(12,26,9) signalLine = macd[‘macd_signal’]

Check if bot has position
has_position = has_open_position(data.symbol, truncated=True)

import numpy as np

def initialize(state):

state.counter = 0

@schedule(interval="1h", symbol="BTCTUSD")

def handler(state, data):

angle = 0

macd_ind = data.macd(12,26,9)

if macd_ind is None:

return

signal = macd_ind['macd_signal']

has_position = has_open_position(data.symbol, truncated=True)

balance_base = float(query_balance_free(data.base))

balance_quoted = float(query_balance_free(data.quoted))

buy_amount = balance_quoted * 0.80 / data.close_last

plot("signal",signal[-1],"BTCTUSD")

if state.counter < 4:

state.counter += 1

else:

state.counter = 0

if state.counter == 4:

lastsignals = signal[-4:]

slope = (lastsignals[-1] - lastsignals[0]) / 3

angle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(slope))

print("slope: ",slope)

print("angle: ",angle)

plot("angle of signal",angle,"BTCTUSD")

if angle > 30 and balance_base

print("-------")

print("Checking for buying possibility of {}".format(data.symbol))

print("buy amount:",buy_amount)

print("buy price:", data.close_last)

create_order(symbol=data.symbol,amount = buy_amount)

elif angle < -30 and has_position:

print("-------")

print("Checking for selling possibility of {}".format(data.symbol))

print("sell amount:",balance_base)

print("sell price:",data.close_last)

close_position(data.symbol)
```

Question:

The first `state.counter = 0` should be indented. I have this error message:

```
Engine error: File "bot.py", line 13. Engine error: @schedule(interval="1h",symbol="BTCUSDT”). Engine error: ^. Engine error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. File "bot.py", line 13 @schedule(interval="1h",symbol="BTCUSDT”) ^ SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typographical quote after BTCUSDT. Replace it with the same quote as in front of BTCUSDT. Never use typographical quotes in programming. If you use an editor that adds them, switch editors. MS Word or Wordpad are unusable for programing. (And, frankly, for everything else as well.)

Comment: thanks for the help!